# install linux kernel 4.4.0-34 kernel ubuntu

Tags: command-line, 16.04, kernel

I have problem with the current ubuntu kernel, and I want to downgrade this.

How can i download all Kernel file, and after install it?

Current version 4.4.0-36 generic
I would like to install 4.4.0-34 generic using terminal

thanks.

Comment: Isn't -34 already on your system? `ls /boot`

Comment: Yes, which command I have to use to install previously kernel?

Comment: If -34 is already in your system as you say, it in not necessary to *install* it. It is only necessary to intterrupt the boot process with the shift key, select Advanced Options and scroll down to -34 and boot into it.